# Extracting dimension measurments using Regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling with regular expression that can extract metrics-like values from statements. Below are some sample I encountered:

Sample questions:

1. Image pixel 200x500 px blur - extract 200x500 px
2. Image pixel 200 x 500 blurring - extract 200 x 500
3. 100.22 x 200.55 x 90.55 mm is the size of the handphone - extract 100.22 x 200.55 x 90.55 mm
4. The mobile phone is 100.22x200.55x90.55 mm in dimension. - extract 100.22x200.55x90.55 mm

So far my code as follows

```js
String str_array[] = new String[4];
  str_array[0] = "Image pixel 200x500 px blur";
  str_array[1] = "Image pixel 200 x 500 blurring";
  str_array[2] = "100.22 x 200.55 x 90.55 mm is the size of the handphone";
  str_array[3] = "The mobile phone is 100.22x200.55x90.55 mm in dimension.";
  for (int i=0;i<str_array.length;i++){
   Pattern pty_resolution_ratio_metrics_try = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)[\\.\\d]+(\\s*)x");
   Matcher matcher_value_metrics_error_try = pty_resolution_ratio_metrics_try.matcher(str_array[i]);
   while (matcher_value_metrics_error_try.find()) {
    System.out.println("index: "+i+"-"+matcher_value_metrics_error_try.group(0));
   }
  }
```

The results from the above codes:

- index: 0-200x
- index: 1-200 x
- index: 2-100.22 x
- index: 2-200.55 x
- index: 3-100.22x
- index: 3-200.55x

Any regular expression suggestions? Need help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to keep recompiling the same pattern. Make that a static final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can this regex:

```
((?:\\d[\\d\\s\\.x]+\\d)(?:\\s*(?:px|mm))?)
```

This regex finds all digits, spaces, periods and x's inside 2 digits. And checks for `px` or `mm` following the numbers.

Alternately you could use a regex that checks to make sure everything is in the right order (no spaces between numbers):

```
((?:(?:[\\d\\.]+)(?:\\s*x\\s*(?:[\\d\\.]+))+)(?:\\s*(?:px|mm))?)
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String texts[] = {"Image pixel 200x500 px blur",
        "Image pixel 200 x 500 blurring",
        "100.22 x 200.55 x 90.55 mm is the size of the handphone",
        "The mobile phone is 100.22x200.55x90.55 mm in dimension"};

    String regex = "((?:\\d[\\d\\s\\.x]+\\d)(?:\\s*(?:px|mm))?)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

    for (int q = 0; q < texts.length; q++){
        Matcher m = p.matcher(texts[q]);
        while (m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group());
        } 
    }
}
```

Prints out the following:

```
200x500 px
200 x 500
100.22 x 200.55 x 90.55 mm
100.22x200.55x90.55 mm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void getDimensions(String text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\d+.?\\d+)(\\s?)x?\\s?)+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Index: " + matcher.start()+" Found: " + matcher.group());
    }

}
```

Try this one

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @ngrj has added, in order to print abbreviations you can modify it to below:

**Pattern.compile("((\d+.?\d+)(\s?)p?x?\s?(mm)?)+")**